# SVG - min-width of container of text

Tags: svg

[image]

How to draw a text in a rect with fixed min-width so that

1. the rect's width will increase if the text is overflowing the rect

OR

2. the text fit the rect like lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" but only when text is too large (not all the time)